# Universal framework: platform not recognized by Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

#### Summary

When creating a universal framework with `lipo` for iphoneos and iphonesimulator, it seems like the app linking the framework doesn't find one of the platforms. I am not sure how Xcode works with universal frameworks.

#### My setup

I have an Xcode project of a Framework, and an app it.

I can build my framework for the "iphoneos" platform (archs: `armv7` `arm64`), and link it into my app that I build for iphoneos.

I can also build my framework for the "iphonesimulator" platform (archs: `i386` `x86_64`), and link it into my app that I build for iphonesimulator.

Now, I want to make a universal framework out of it (i.e. I want to have only one framework for iphoneos and iphonesimulator. Given my framework `foo.framework`, I do something like:

```
cp -r Debug-iphoneos/foo.framework .
rm foo.framework/foo
lipo Debug-iphoneos/foo.framework/foo Debug-iphonesimulator/foo.framework/foo -create -output foo.framework/foo
```

It results in a framework where the `foo` binary has archs `armv7`, `arm64`, `i386`, `x86_64`. But when linking it into my app, it either works only for iphoneos, or only for iphonesimulator, but not both.

Since my app works when building for the simulator and using the simulator framework, and it also works when building for iphoneos and the iphoneos framework, I believe my code is fine, and all the symbols are effectively there.

When I use the universal framework, it seems like Xcode doesn't find any symbols for one of the two platforms. I thought it might be related to the `Info.plist` (that has a "supported platforms" field and that I don't adapt to the universal setup), but completely removing the `Info.plist` doesn't solve the problem.

Is there a documentation somewhere explaining what xcode expects from a universal framework? I understand I need all 4 archs in a fat binary, but nobody ever mentions the `Info.plist`, and I did not find any documentation explaining how Xcode uses the universal framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that there are actually different Swift submodules for the different architectures, so they need to be copied independently:

```
cp -r Debug-iphoneos/foo.framework/Modules/foo.swiftmodule/* <universal_foo.framework>/Modules/foo.swiftmodule/
```

And I was assuming that they were the same for all architectures, resulting in some of them lacking in my "universal framework", which explains why they were ignored.